# How to decrement decimal values in javascript

Tags: javascript, subtraction, addition

I'm trying to implement a decrement functionality for decimal values in js

On clicking a button the below should happen

```
1.22 -> 1.21
3.00 -> 2.99
1.2345 -> 1.2344
```

How could I do that, below is my code

```
var decimals = 1,
    stringC = String(positionData.volume),
    value = parseFloat(positionData.volume);
if (stringC.includes(".")) {
    const splitted = stringC.split(".");
    decimals = splitted[1];
}
const length = decimals?.length;
if (length > 0) {
    decimals = "0.";
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i == length - 1) {
            decimals += "1";
        }
        decimals += "0";
    }
}
console.log(decimals);
decimals = parseFloat(decimals).toFixed(2);
setCloseValue((value) =>
    (parseFloat(value) + decimals).toString()
);
```

Above is my code but it is appending the values as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:** I just realized only decrementing was requested. Oh well - now this answer works for incrementing too... and also steps larger than ±1.*

---

I would solve this as follows:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')

function applyStep (step) {
  const decimals = input.value.split('.')[1]?.length ?? 0
  const stepSize = 10 ** -decimals
  input.value = (Number(input.value) + stepSize * step).toFixed(decimals)
}

document.getElementById('increment').addEventListener('click', () => applyStep(1))
document.getElementById('decrement').addEventListener('click', () => applyStep(-1))
```

```html
<input id="input" value="1.23" />
<button id="increment">Inc</button>
<button id="decrement">Dec</button>
```

What I do here is this: I first check how many decimals we have after the `.` (defaulting to 0 if there is no dot).

Then I calculate a step size of 10<sup>-decimals</sup>, e.g. with 3 decimals we get 10<sup>-3</sup> which is 0.001.

Then I add the given step (+1 or -1) multiplied by step size to the numeric value and reformat it with the previous number of decimals before writing it back into the field.

Note that this won't work with numbers that go beyond the precision limits of JavaScripts default number type. If that is desired, a more complicated approach would be needed.

It could be done by handling integer and fractional parts separately as two BigInts, but it needs a lot of thought when it comes to carry and negative values. Here is a possible solution:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')

function applyStep (step) {
  if (!input.value.match(/^-?\d+(\.\d*)?$/)) throw new Error('Invalid format')
  const [strIntegerPart, strFractionalPart = ''] = input.value.split('.')
  let bnIntegerPart = BigInt(strIntegerPart)
  let bnFractionalPart = BigInt(strFractionalPart)
  const decimals = strFractionalPart.length
  const maxFractionalPart = 10n ** BigInt(decimals)
  let negative = strIntegerPart.startsWith('-') && (bnIntegerPart || bnFractionalPart)
  
  if (negative) {
    bnIntegerPart *= -1n
    step *= -1n
  }
  
  bnFractionalPart += step
  const offset = bnFractionalPart < 0n ? maxFractionalPart - 1n : 0n
  const carry = (bnFractionalPart - offset) / maxFractionalPart
  bnIntegerPart += carry
  bnFractionalPart -= carry * maxFractionalPart
  
  if (bnIntegerPart < 0n) {
    if (bnFractionalPart) {
      bnIntegerPart += 1n
      bnFractionalPart = maxFractionalPart - bnFractionalPart
    }
    bnIntegerPart *= -1n
    negative = !negative
  }
  
  let newValue = bnIntegerPart.toString()
  if (decimals > 0) newValue += '.' + bnFractionalPart.toString().padStart(decimals, '0')
  if (negative && (bnIntegerPart || bnFractionalPart)) newValue = '-' + newValue
  
  input.value = newValue
}

document.getElementById('increment').addEventListener('click', () => applyStep(1n))
document.getElementById('decrement').addEventListener('click', () => applyStep(-1n))
```

```html
<input id="input" value="1.23" />
<button id="increment">Inc</button>
<button id="decrement">Dec</button>
```

Both these solutions will work with steps other than 1 and -1 too.

Comment: If I give the input as 100, it is incrementing to 100.9 and on the next increment it is changing to 101.0

How to make it 100.11 and it should become 101.0 only if it reaches 100.99 Because logically 101.0 is possible only after 100.99

Can you help me with that?

Comment: I don't understand - I tried both examples and if I enter 100 (without any decimals), it increments to 101, as expected, if I enter 100.0 it increments to 100.1, if I enter 100.00 it increments to 100.01, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const decrementVarable = (decimal)=>{
  let decToString = decimal.toString().split('.')
  if(decToString.length > 1){
    let value = decToString[1]
    let number = Number('1'+ '0'.repeat(value.length))
    let numWithoutDecimal = ((decimal * number)-1)/number
    return numWithoutDecimal
  }

  return (decimal-1);
}
```

use this code just pass your decimal

Answer (score 0):

Floating points are usually messy. If you really need it to be 100% precise, use an integer variable, increment that by 1 in each iteration, test for when it reaches 100, and then, for the actual calculation, take your variable and divide it by 100 to obtain the decimal value you need.